# What's causing React Native componentDidMount being called none stop, indefinitely?

Tags: react-native, react-component

Here is the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MovieList from './MovieList';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MovieList />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

Here is the MoveList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class MovieList extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount")
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        // console.log("responseJson: " + JSON.stringify(responseJson))
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.movies,
        }, function(){

        });
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
        <MovieList name='Valeera' />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});
```

The code for downloading the movie is from the official getting started tutorial [networking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#using-fetch), the only differences is that I put the code in a new js file called MovieList and include it as a component in the App.js

With the above code, the componentDidMount is being called none stop, and printing the movie list indefinitely, and eventually the app will crash.

Isn't the componentDidMount supposed to be called only once? What's causing it to be called indefinitely? What did I do wrong in the above code?

Comment: try once again commenting the setState inside the componentDidMount , may be it's the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having your component `MovieList` embedded in the render-method of the component itself. This is creating the endless loop. Probably you only need to remove it there as your FlatList seems complete.